# How to remove "Void" option on an envelope for CarbonCopy recipient in DocuSign?

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

How to remove "Void" option for CarbonCopy recipients in DocuSign?

Hi there.
By default, the CarbonCopy recipient can Void an envelope.[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv3wH.png). How to disable this ability? Can I do this using C# DocuSign SDK?
Thanks in advance for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Carbon Copy recipients (CC) *Cannot* void an envelope unless they are the sender of the envelope and/or they are also a signer on the envelope.

If you send an envelope and make yourself a CC, you can always void the envelope because you own it.

Please try again and use some other email address as a CC, make sure this email is not also a signer on the same envelope.

Comment: The problem is that the emails are different, I used a completely different email than sender's only for CC.

Comment: every email is different and you still see void option?

Comment: This would be a bug, please contact customer support at support.docusign.com